# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch (size [1 x 1] ~= size [1 x :?])

Tags: matlab, dimensions

I wanted to be:

```
arr(2,1) = arr(2,1) + abs(5.0 minus 5.1);% where I(1,a) is 5.0 and I(1,a+1)is 5.1
```

Why couldn't I add the below two together? I got this error message:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch (size [1 x 1] ~= size [1 x :?]).
>
> Function 'MATLAB Function' (#620.435.485), line 23, column 2:
>   "arr(count,1) = arr(count,1) + abs(I(1,a)-I(1,a+1))"
>   Launch diagnostic report.

'I' is declared in worskspace as:

```
I =

 5.0000    5.1000    5.2000    5.2000
90.0000   85.0000   80.0000   20.0000


integ_signal=zeros(5,4);
a=zeros(10);
arr=zeros(5,4);
count=2;
a=1;
integ_signal(count,1)=  integ_signal(count-1,1);
 arr(count,1) = integ_signal(count,1); 
arr(count,1) = arr(count,1) + abs(I(1,a)-I(1,a+1));
```

The system is shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00dNm.jpg). The complete code is below:

```
 function integ_signal= fcn(I,V,count,oldval)

 integ_signal=zeros(5,1);
 a=zeros(10);
 arr=zeros(2,4);
 %b=zeros(10);
 integ_signal=oldval; 
 coder.extrinsic('load');
 load('data.mat','I');
 a=1;
 %b=1;
 if count==1
     integ_signal(count,1) = 10; % Initial Condition
 end

 if count>1

  integ_signal(count,1)=  integ_signal(count-1,1);
  arr(count,1) = integ_signal(count,1);
  arr(count,1) = arr(count,1) + abs(I(1,a)-I(1,a+1));

  end
 a=a+1;
 % b++;
 end
```

Dear Sir, I keep getting this error, my desired output is to get abs(I(2,ii(a))-I(2,ii(a)-1) so that when ii(a)=2, I want I(2,2) minus I(2,1) which is 5.1 minus 5.0 : Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 2. The valid range is 1-1.
"2"
. at this line:
    arr(1,ii(a)) = arr(1,ii(a)) + abs(I(2,ii(a))-I(2,ii(a)-1));.

I define I as the following in .mat file:

save data -v7.3 'I'
load('data.mat','I');
I =

Columns 1 through 6

```
     0    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000
5.0000    5.1000    5.2000    5.2000    5.5000    5.9000
```

Column 7

```
6.0000
6.0000
```

Comment: I don't get any errors when I copy paste your code. How does your sample code differ from the real one?

Comment: Dear Sir, thanks for your reply, it pinpoints at this line for error
arr(count,1) = arr(count,1) + abs(I(1,a)-I(1,a+1));. My original code is written in Matlab Function Block

Comment: Do you mean there is nothing wrong to add these two? arr(count,1) = arr(count,1) + abs(I(1,a)-I(1,a+1));

Comment: What happens if you copy-paste your sample code? Does it work? If yes, try to create a new example where it fails. If it doesn't work; I don't know what could be wrong.

Comment: Yeah it runs perfectly if I put it in Matlab workspace, however, when it is in Matlab Function Block, i got the above error. i am going to put the complete code and system here, not too long though

Comment: The complete code is here:http://imgur.com/mwj0vAZ
and the system:http://imgur.com/poQw0wb

Comment: I have updated the complete code in my above post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you call your code with `count` as a vector. Also, it seems like you're missing a loop. (If not, why the `a = a + 1`?)

```
a = zeros(10);
```

followed by

```
a = 1;
```

does not make much sense. What is your input variable `I`? What do you want `load('data.mat','I')` to do?

If I'm correct, try something like:

```
for ii = 1:length(count)
    if count(ii) == 1
       integ_signal(count(ii),1) = 10; % Initial Condition
    end

    if count(ii) > 1
       integ_signal(count(ii),1)=  integ_signal(count(ii)-1,1); % Or, (count(ii-1),1)
       arr(count(ii),1) = integ_signal(count(ii),1);
       arr(count(ii),1) = arr(count(ii),1) + abs(I(1,a)-I(1,a+1));
    end
    a = a + 1;
end
```

You probably need to tweak this in some way, but I think it may help you a bit.

Comment: Dear Sir,thanks for your reply.1. Yeah, it is my mistake, shouldn't have a = zeros(10); followed by a=1;.

For the second part of your answer, it did solve the Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch issue, may I know what is the reason behind?

Comment: However, I got another error message which I have yet to figure out again: Simulation stopped due to out of bounds error.

Comment: I believe there are several mistakes in this function. Depending on the size of `I`, `a` is probably not used right. It will be out of bounds if `I` has less columns than `count`. I don't know what would be correct, you will have to try. Also, I guess you want to use `if ii = 1` etc, not `if count(ii) == 1`, as it is above. Assuming you want your indices to be `1`, `2`, ... In that case, it would be `for ii = 1:count`, and all `count(ii)` with just `ii`.

Comment: Dear Sir, I keep getting this error, my desired output is to get abs(I(2,ii(a))-I(2,ii(a)-1) so that when ii(a)=2, I want I(2,2) minus I(2,1) which is 5.1 minus 5.0 : Index expression out of bounds. Attempted to access element 2. The valid range is 1-1.
"2"
. at this line:
    arr(1,ii(a)) = arr(1,ii(a)) + abs(I(2,ii(a))-I(2,ii(a)-1));.

I define I as the following in .mat file:

save data -v7.3 'I'
load('data.mat','I');
I =

  Columns 1 through 6

         0    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    4.0000    5.0000
    5.0000    5.1000    5.2000    5.2000    5.5000    5.9000

Comment: @user2563812: This is too much info in a comment. I suggest you ask a new question where you explain your new problem.